# Factory girls with primary key of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am making a rails application and now trying to test my application.

Now I have a Table with the primary key in string, so I created factory girls model like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :table_setting do
    setting_id 'some_api_key' # this is the primary key
    setting_value 'some_api_key_value'
  end
end
```

and in the spec file, I created the instance. but somehow it returned like

```
#<table_setting 
   setting_id: 1, 
   setting_value: "apikey_value"
 >
```

I wanted to use a string primary key but it only gives me incremental integers. Can somebody tell me how to deal with this?

---

**After some tries**

Now I figured out how the problem lies within my model (or mysql database)

When I look at the datatype of setting_id in MySQL, I get the datatype of INTEGER, 
But When I look at the datatype of table_setting in rails console like

```
> TableSetting
```

then it shows that the setting_id is of the datatype of STRING. And this has been puzzling me..

Comment: Have you checked that you can actually create TableSettings in for example Rails console to be sure that the problem isn't actually in your model?

Comment: I just checked it and now I came to know that the setting_id is set in the form of INTEGER. but when I check mysql It showed STRING. 

Like @sanfor said the problem lies within model...

Comment: Wrote an answer for future reference.

Comment: I am working on it... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Factory Girl uses the models as they are, it doesn't modify the fields in that sense. Thus the problem must be in your model. Please check that the model works okay in for example Rails console.